# How to make a 3D model for Unity 5

Tags: 3d

I'm using Unity 5 to make a small game (I'm a beginner) and I want to make a 3D model of a character. I'm not sure what software there is to do this and if there is some, I would like it to be preferably free, but if anyone can help or give advice I would appreciate it. I want to be able to make a 3D model and then import it to Unity 5. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think questions asking for tool recommendations are on topic here. Computer Graphics SE is a Q&A site for computer graphics researchers and programmers.

Comment: [Relevant meta post.](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/143/16)

Comment: A quick search over at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) likely meets your requirements. I have used it in the past to make 3D models and export to model files which Unity can import.

I would highly recommend watching some tutorial videos before using it:

- [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF6qkByl-_M)
- [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y__uzGKmxt8)
- [three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zd1AI198I8)

[Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) can help answer more questions about Blender.

Comment: Please do not spread the idea of using the .obj format. Please choose a more capable format to promote, whether exporting manually or using the .blend directly, which will probably be best for a beginner's purposes.

Comment: Although I do not agree with your comment, this is not the right place for that debate. I have edited my answer to remove the OBJ reference.

Comment: I'd love to hear your thoughts. Give us a link if you ever post them.

Comment: Post a question and watch everyone fire shots :-)